# How to make an installable Perl program with makefile/autoconf?

Tags: perl, makefile, configure

I have software written in Perl, now I want to release it and I want it to be an installation package like the other GNU software, which can be installed by typing:

```
./configure; make; make install
```

I noticed that in autoconf's package, most of the code is written in Perl and the Perl scripts are generated by running "make". That's exactly what I want to do. How would I go about doing that?

===
Added

Thank you for your nice answer! But what I wrote is not a module, it's actually a set of scripts which will do something in a pipe, the only thing I need to setup is the locations of some program I used in the Perl scripts. Is there any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 10):

The process used by [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker) and [Module::Install](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module%3a%3aInstall) is very similar.

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

If you're set on using the specific command chain you posted, you can place the following in file `configure`:

```
#!/bin/sh
perl Makefile.PL
```

If you're not set on using the specific command chain you posted, there's also [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module%3a%3aBuild).

```
perl Build.PL
./Build
./Build test
./Build install
```

I use Module::Build personally.

Comment: For completeness sake, the `Makefile.PL` comes from employing [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://p3rl.org/ExtUtils::MakeMaker) or [Module::Install](http://p3rl.org/Module::Install).

Comment: @daxim, Thanks, incorporated. Also mentioned Module::Build.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer! But what I wrote is not a module, it's actually a set of scripts which will do something in a pipe, the only thing I need to setup is the locations of some program I used in the perl scripts. Is there any suggestion on this?

Comment: @sohutu, I know you meant scripts. All of the modules I named can install them too. With Module::Build, see `script_files`. As for getting the path from the user, that's an entirely different question.

Comment: @ikegami,Thanks a lot! So do you have any idea on getting the path? What I want to do is generate the final perl program according to the environments found by configure....Thank you very much!

Comment: @sohutu, "How do I get the path?" is too vague a question.

Answer (score 0):

In the Makefile.am that's where your perl scripts reside, add the line

```
 dist_bin_SCRIPTS = your_perl_program
```